# Definition of a lattice point being primitve

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was reading an article and came across
the following definition: a lattice 
point is called $\it{primitive}$ if it 
is part of a basis of the lattice.

Suppose I have a lattice $\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Does "primitive" mean, first fix one basis and then 
if $P$ is in this particular basis, then $P$ is primitive or does it mean $P$ 
has to be in some basis of $\Lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent to a gcd condition: it means the point is not an integer multiple of another point in the lattice, regarded as vectors.

There is a little work in showing that this means a basis can be constructed with the given point as one of the vectors.

Writing this with gcd is basis dependent. If you already have an integral basis $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n,$ and you write your
$$ w = a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_n v_n$$ with integers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n,$ then $w$ is primitive if and only if $$ \gcd(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)=1. $$  Note that, if the gcd were some $g \neq 1,$ you could divide $w$ by $g$ and still have integral coefficients.

Comment: Could you possibly tell me what the gcd condition states by any chance? Thank you!